# DB2 Change Journal Receiver Size

Tags: db2, iseries

We are running DB2 on our iSeries, and there is a journal + journal receiver created. The current size of the journal receiver is 200MB (found using the DSPJRNRCVA command). Is there a way to change this value?
If so, how? And what is the minimum that it can be changed to?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think you want to change the size of the receiver?